# MySQL SUBSTR() function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare $images, $uploads but the outputs have different names:

```
$images = '/fiscalapplications/uploads/Image_00314_20200122.pdf';  
$uploads = 'Image_00314_20200122.pdf';
```

How do I do SUBSTR for the $images to = Image_00314_20200122.pdf

```
<?php
//pulling images from mysql colum1
require_once 'database_connection.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT check_pic_path FROM checklog");


$images = []; // store a list of images from the database

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $images[] = $row['check_pic_path'] . "<br>";
}

//pulling pictures from specific path
$dir = "fiscalapplications/uploads";

$uploads = []; // store a list of files on disk

if(is_dir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        $uploads[] = $file . "<br>";
    }
}
}

//attempting to compare $image to $upload
$compare = array_diff($images, $uploads);
print_r($compare);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to check if the image file names are the same?

Comment: I would suggest you *not* put the "<br>" in the array itself. Get in the habit of always separating data from presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `basename()` to remove the directory from a pathname:

```
$images[] = basename($row['check_pic_path']) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Sometimes simple is best! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it may be

```
SUBSTRINT_INDEX(tablename.imagefield, '/', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

$uploadsnew  = substr($images , strrpos($images , '/') + 1);
strrpos gets the position of the last occurrence of the slash; substr returns everything after that position.

if there is no slash this doesn't work correctly since strrpos returns false. Here's a more robust version:

$pos = strrpos($url, '/');
$uploadsnew  = $pos === false ? $url : substr($images , $pos + 1);

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$images = $images ?: '';
$uploads = substr($images, ($pos = strrpos($images, '/')) ? $pos : 0);
```

In MySQL:

```
if( ifnull( locate( '/', check_pic_path ), 0 ) > 0, substring_index( check_pic_path, '/', -1 ), check_pic_path )
```